# How to split string after x characters and on on last space character in vb

Tags: string, vb.net

What i want to do is, after X amount of characters, split the string on last whitespace, and then after the next X amount of characters repeat.

Till now i have something like this , using regex but i get error on "Function"

```
Dim input = "This is a long sentence with more than 18 letters."
Dim output = Regex.Split(input, "(.{1,18})(?:\s|$)").Where(Function(x) x.Length > 0).ToList()
```

Comment: What seems to be the error that you are getting?

Comment: If you have an error on Function, maybe you are using a version of .NET that doesn't support anonymous method. Your code seems to be working well with newer version.

Comment: i m trying this on 1.1 :)